# Why is Nokogiri giving me multiple results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an HTML string with Nokogiri but I'm getting some recursion issue and I can't figure out why.

Given these commands:

```
string = <h3>Lancers were arranged.&nbsp;</h3>
         <div>Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.</div>
         <br>She leaned. He lit a <b>candle</b>.
         They followed him in silence, their feet falling in soft thuds on the thickly carpeted stairs.<br>

body = Nokogiri::HTML(string)
result = []
body.traverse { |node| result << node }
```

I would expect an array of the above elements. Instead I get given this:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x3fde1f3d5274 name="html">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88d330 "Lancers were arranged. ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56a68 name="h3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88d330 "Lancers were arranged. ">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88c764 "Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88cd04 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88c764 "Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88c0fc name="br">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88b9e0 "She leaned. He lit a ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6c60 "candle">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88b5f8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6c60 "candle">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6454 ". They followed him in silence
their feet falling in soft thuds on the thickly carpeted stairs.">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1eba5f54 name="br">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56f7c name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56a68 name="h3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88d330 "Lancers were arranged. ">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88cd04 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88c764 "Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88c0fc name="br">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88b9e0 "She leaned. He lit a ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88b5f8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6c60 "candle">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6454 ". They followed him in silence
their feet falling in soft thuds on the thickly carpeted stairs.">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1eba5f54 name="br">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea575e4 name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56f7c name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56a68 name="h3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88d330 "Lancers were arranged. ">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88cd04 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88c764 "Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88c0fc name="br">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88b9e0 "She leaned. He lit a ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88b5f8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6c60 "candle">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6454 ". They followed him in silence
their feet falling in soft thuds on the thickly carpeted stairs.">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1eba5f54 name="br">]>]>
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x3fde1f3d6084 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x3fde1f3d5274 name="html">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea575e4 name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56f7c name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1ea56a68 name="h3" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88d330 "Lancers were arranged. ">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88cd04 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88c764 "Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88c0fc name="br">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1e88b9e0 "She leaned. He lit a ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1e88b5f8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6c60 "candle">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fde1eba6454 ". They followed him in silence
their feet falling in soft thuds on the thickly carpeted stairs.">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fde1eba5f54 name="br">]>]>]>]
```

Sorry for the length. Can anyone help me figure out why this happens? And/or how to prevent it?

Comment: Please paste the input and output HTML separately. Don't use a single-line string or a stringified object. It's hard to follow, and if you had done that I think you'd see the problem (`Element` objects include their children, even when stringified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse incomplete html, Nokogiri automatically adds doctype and html and body elements. You have to parse it like this to avoid this behavior:

```
body = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(your_html)
```

If you want result to be and array of elements excluding text nodes you can do this:

```
result = body.xpath('./*')
```

Then the result (converted to string for clarity) will be:

```
["<h3>Lancers were arranged. </h3>",
 "<div>Gabriel found himself partnered with Miss Ivors.</div>",
 "<br>",
 "<b>candle</b>",
 "<br>"]
```

Comment: That helps half the issue, it seems. Significantly less repeating going on, but elements like the first `<h3>` are repeated twice.

Comment: Just tried it and it is not repeated, this is what I got ["text", "h3", "text", "div", "br", "text", "text", "b", "text", "br", "#document-fragment"]. Maybe the last element confuses you. It is the whole fragment you called traverse on.

Comment: That is _so_ close. The `xpath('./*')` cuts out everything _not_ in an element though. The problem with the HTML code is that it's automatically generated and I can't predict which paragraphs will be wrapped and which won't.

Comment: `*` won't include text nodes. You could do something like `./*|./text()` but it's simpler to use `children` like @Alex Bullard says.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because `traverse` calls the provided block on itself and all its children recursively. So it adds every node of your html string to the `result` array instead of just the top level nodes. The 'multiple results' you are seeing is a result of how `inspect` is defined for Nokogiri nodes. For example the 3rd element in the returned array represents the `h3` node, but also prints all of its children, which includes the `text` node that is the 2nd element of the array.

If you want `result` to include a reference to every node in the document than this is the right way to do it. If you just want top level nodes use `children`